# web service con base de datos en .net mvc

Tags: .net, wcf

estoy tratando de implementar un web Service en .net mvc con WCF:
cuando implemento los metodos de la interface en la clase del servicio e instancio el contexto de la base de datos me aparece el siguiente error y me dice que agregue una referencia pero no se de donde agregarla:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahi donde te sale el error puede presionar las teclas CTRL+ . te saldra una sugerencia para agregar la referencia

Comment: sii, eso lo se, pero no encuentro esa referencia, no encuentro "Microsof.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, version= 2.0"

Comment: Puedes agregarlo desde NPM, dale click derecho a tu proyecto luego hay una opcion que dice el Nuget Package Manager, ahi buscas entity framework y lo agregas a tu proyecto, con eso ya podras agregar la referencia.

Comment: si, lo hice por el nuget, muchas gracias